# Ошибка процесса 0xc000013a

Tags: c++, windows

Простая программа, которая выводит в консоль текущие значения даты и времени:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

int main(void)
{
    time_t tt = time(NULL);
#pragma warning ( disable : 4996 )
    tm* tim = localtime(&tt);
    std::cout << tim->tm_mday << '.' << tim->tm_mon + 1 << '.' << tim->tm_year + 1900 << std::endl << tim->tm_hour << ':' << tim->tm_min << ':' << tim->tm_sec <<std::endl;
    delete tim;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Завершается с кодом 0xc000013a. Как исправить?

Answer (score 6):

`localtime` использует какое-то внутреннее представление, указатель на которое она и возвращает. Ненужно и нельзя его удалять, поэтому уберите `delete`.